# Wordpress - only the homepage can be found

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, frontpage

My wordpress site works perfectly. My pages I create in Wordpress admin panel are displayed in widgets, so if you click on a nav menu item, a div appears and displays the content of it. Perfect. But as soon as I would like to write a new .php page and try to open it like writing "mywebsite dot com / confirmation.php" in the address bar, the bar displays "mywebsite com / confirmation.php" but there is the front page on the screen again. Even if I write anything else after mywebsite dot com/, it shows the index page, no matter what it is.. I tried to write "mywebsite dot com/sdjfhskhdfkshdfkjhsdf" and it still worked, displayed the home page again.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked that your .htaccess is correct?

Comment: @LTasty I'm really not sure how should it look like or how is it correct/incorrect. When I opened it in Dreamweaver, it said:


    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your permalinks and make sure your htaccess is writable when you do so. Also can you get to your "/confirmation" page if you click view page from inside the page in dashboard? Also try changing the template that your new page is using.